# Change Date format - Convert to Date Class

Tags: r, dataframe, date, format, as.date

I have a  column of dates that were read in as character. I want to produce a data class with my desired format (say, US-style, 08/28/2020).
But, all solutions to change format, produce character class, or produce date class with standard format (2020-08-28)
This is a reproducible example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(date=c("08/27/2020", "08/28/2020", "08/29/2020"), cases=c(5,6,7))
class(df1$date)


df1$date1<- format(as.Date(df1$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), "%m/%d/%Y")
class(df1$date1)

df1$date2<-as.Date(parse_date_time(df1$date,"%m/%d/%Y"))
class(df1$date2)

df1$date3<- as.Date(df1$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
class(df1$date3)

df1
```

As you can see data1 has my desired format while it is not date class. In addition, date2 and date3 are  Date class while they produce undesired format.

```
   date    cases  date1      date3      date2
```

1| 08/27/2020 | 5 | 08/27/2020  |2020-08-27 | 2020-08-27|

2| 08/28/2020 |    6 | 08/28/2020  |2020-08-28 | 2020-08-28|

3| 08/29/2020 |    7 | 08/29/2020  |2020-08-29 | 2020-08-29|

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Check again. Running `as.Date(df1$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")` returns an object of class `Date` on my machine.

Comment: Date class is of fixed format `YYYY-MM-DD` in R. Anything else would be character class.

Comment: As you see in the links above, it is possible to change print format, but please also note relevant objections in comments therein.

Comment: Thank you @setfan. Yes. It returns an object of class date but the output format is not desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Date` class is always shown like "2020-08-27" in R. That's R's standard `Date`. To reformat it into something different you can use `strftime`. It assumes a Date class and outputs a `character` object with your desired format, e.g.

```
df1$date2
[1] "2020-08-27" "2020-08-28" "2020-08-29"

class(df1$date2)
[1] "Date"

strftime(df1$date2, format="%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "08/27/2020" "08/28/2020" "08/29/2020"

class(strftime(df1$date2, format="%m/%d/%Y"))
[1] "character"
```

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with dates and time `lubridate` package is really handy: https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/.

In this case we could use `mdy` function (month, day, year) for date and date1.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(c(date, date1), mdy))
```

```
  date       cases date1      date3     
  <date>     <dbl> <date>     <date>    
1 2020-08-27     5 2020-08-27 2020-08-27
2 2020-08-28     6 2020-08-28 2020-08-28
3 2020-08-29     7 2020-08-29 2020-08-29
```

Comment: The problem is that Date class is of fixed format, as @Ronak Shah mentioned.